# "Transitory" Vs "Elusive"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

We know that:

> **Elusive** means: "difficult to describe, find, achieve, or remember."

And also:

> **Transitory** means: "lasting for only a short time."

Now please let me know which choice works better in the following sentences from among these two words:

> 1 - Language is a ..................... skill / subject. It has to be reviewed everyday; otherwise, it will fade away.
>
> 2 - This word is just .....................; I cannot memorize it. I've already read it 20 times, but every time I need to recall it, I fail!

For me, both of these two words work in both of my sentences properly, but I doubt if they are natural and idiomatic in these senses.

Answer (score 1):

These definitions do not sound particularly synonymous to me, but I will try to clarify how these words are different:

Something that is "elusive" is hard to find, hard to *catch*, hard to *hold*, hard to *understand*, hard to *retain*, etc.

> An avid birdwatcher, his lifelong dream was to photograph the **elusive** Dulit Frogmouth of Borneo.

The word can be applied to concepts as well:

> Understanding the deepest aspects of Hegel's philosophy can seem frustrating and **elusive** -- the moment you think you've wrapped your head around it, Hegel will introduce some new aspect that seems to negate everything that came before.

"Transitory", on the other hand, is something of a ["ten dollar word"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ten-dollar_word) that means *temporary* -- that is, "lasting for a short period of time".  As with any sophisticated word, it can sound better in some contexts, and more educated when used properly.

> William was an incorrigible playboy who never had anything but a **transitory** affection for any of his many lovers -- at least, until he met Madison.

"Elusive" works for both of your sentences.  "Transitory" kind of works for the first, although I would not say *language* is temporary.  Language *fluency* makes more sense:

> Fluency in a particular language is **transitory**. You have to practice everyday, otherwise it will quickly fade.

(Edit) In some limited contexts, perhaps, "temporary/transitory" can be substituted for "elusive", but the meaning is still different.  For example:

> It's always better to get a good night's sleep than rely on the **transitory** buzz you get from a cup of coffee.
>
> It's always better to get a good night's sleep than rely on the **elusive** buzz you get from a cup of coffee.

The first sentence says the buzz lasts only a short time.  The second suggests the buzz is not only *impermanent*, but also *undependable*.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much @Andrew for both the helpful post and also editing my thread. :) Just, could you please let me know whether the word **"temporary"** can work as "elusive" works?

Comment: @A-friend  No, the words mean different things. See my edit.